# Use secret for ValidatingWebhookConfiguration

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

In order to make my ValidatingWebhookConfiguration works, I have to do a bunch of openssl commands, and then I copy paste (or sed) the certificate authority in my deploy.yaml file where my webhook is defined. But this is not really clean. I know I can put my CA in a Secret, but how can I assess this secret in the ValidatingWebhookConfiguration please ?

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  name: webhook-test
webhooks:
- name: my.webhook.frick
  failurePolicy: Fail
  clientConfig:
    caBundle: CA_BUNDLE_THAT_I_HAVE_TO_PASTE_BY_HAND
    service:
      name: validating-svc
      namespace: default
      path: /services/validate
  rules:
      ...
```

All the openssl commands :

```
openssl genrsa -out certs/ca.key 2048;
openssl req -new -x509 -key certs/ca.key -out certs/ca.crt -config certs/ca_config.txt
openssl genrsa -out certs/chris.pem 2048;
openssl req -new -key certs/chris.pem -subj "/CN=validating-svc.default.svc" -out certs/chris.csr -config certs/chris_config.txt;
openssl x509 -req -in certs/chris.csr -CA certs/ca.crt -CAkey certs/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out certs/chris-crt.pem;
export CA_BUNDLE=$(cat certs/ca.crt | base64 | tr -d '\n'); # Copy paste in deploy.yaml
```

The goal in the long run is to package my webhook project with helm.

Comment: what would go into `certs/ca_config.txt` & `certs/chris_config.txt`? this would help understand openssl a bit better. Appreciate the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a controller for injecting the CA bundle into the webhook’s ValidatingWebhookConfiguration and MutatingWebhookConfiguration resources in order to allow the Kubernetes API server to ‘trust’ the webhook API server. The [ca injector](https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts/ca-injector/) of [cert manager](https://cert-manager.io) does exactly that and you can use it as a reference because the [source code](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/tree/master/pkg/controller/cainjector) is open source.